# Detect power button pressed in Accessibility Service

Tags: android, android-service, accessibility

I need to open application when power and volume+ buttons long pressed.
Does its possible to detect power button pressing in Accessibility Service? Or maybe exist another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the Volume button up or down on the `onKeyEvent()` method, but you can't detect the power button, due to the android functionality.